# How to get command prompt output which is in the form of .txt inside a python script?

Tags: python

I'm using this code `os.system("dcapgen.exe C:\\Users\\folder\\a.dcap")` in my python script to run this command **dcapgen.exe C:\Users\folder\a.dcap**. This command generates .txt file in its current directory. I want to use this generated .txt file further in my code. How to do this? I don't want command log output. Thanks!
I'm new to python programming.

Comment: Try it with subprocess

Answer (score 1):

Try the `open` method: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

It is especially handy in Python that you can surround this method with a `with` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use `subprocess.run` to run the command and capture STDOUT to get the output from the command:

```
proc = subprocess.run(['dcapgen.exe', 'C:\\Users\\folder\\a.dcap'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
```

Now you can get the STDOUT from the `stdout` attribute:

```
proc.stdout
```

You might need to strip-off CR-LF from end:

```
proc.stdout.rstrip()
```

---

**Edit:**

If you're using Python 2.7, you can use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
out = subprocess.check_output(['dcapgen.exe', 'C:\\Users\\folder\\a.dcap'])
```

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. `subprocess.run` only works for python 3.5 or newer. so, in my case, what to do? Also i have to analyse that txt file further like searching it for some keywords etc. I'm using `os.system("DCAPTraceGen.exe %s" % os.path.join(r, file))` for applying this command to files present in different directory and now i have to analyse those txt files one by one.

Comment: by using `out = subprocess.check_output(['dcapgen.exe', 'C:\\Users\\folder\\a.dcap'])`, we do not get .txt file that the command will generate, but rather string log that we get after we enter this command in command prompt. dcapgen.exe is generating a.txt in its current directory and i want to access that file, not its log.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a simple C program that writes "Hello World" to a text file, called `text.txt`, as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  FILE * fp = fopen ("text.txt","w");
  fprintf(fp, "Hello world\n");
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling the C program will give you an executable, in our case it will be called `a.out`. The command `./a.out` will run the executable and print to file.

Now let's assume we have a Python script in *the same folder*. In order to execute the C program AND read from file you'll have to do something like this

```
import os

# Run the C generated executable
os.system('./a.out')

# At this point a `text.txt` file exists, so it can be accessed
# The "r" option means you want to read. "w" or "a" for write and append respectively
# The file is now accesible with assigned name `file` 
with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
  file.read() # To get the full content of the file
  file.readline() # To read a single line
  for line in file: # Handy way to traverse the file line by line
    print(line)
```

**EDIT(s)**
If you want to follow through keep in mind that:

1. This is a step-by-step Linux approach. I know little about Windows, but I am assuming executables are ran a bit differently. I'm sure you know how.
2. If you have your files across different folders you'll need the path to the files to be specified, not just the file name.

Comment: i cannot use `with open("text.txt", "r") as file:` because i don't know the resultant .txt file name. It will be different for different .dcap file.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done because .txt file that will be generated is not getting traced in command prompt. we can only get cmd log output using **subprocess** which is being suggested by other answers. so, we can get access to the generated file by using its path and full name which we know because its naming follows some pattern and location is fixed, like this

`generated_text_file = original_file_name+"_some_addition.txt"
 with open(generated_text_file, 'r') as file1:
 s = file1.read().replace('/n','')`